# How to get everything after a = sign in my urls as an event in GTM with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get some custom JS working in Google Tag Manager. What I am trying to do is make it so that anything after an = sign in my outgoing links is tracked as an event in GTM.

For example my links look like this...

https://www.example.org/go/company/?aid=link1

https://www.example.org/go/company/?param=link2

In the urls above I want to capture both "link1" and "link2" as my link id in GTM.

This is the code I am trying to make work with no luck so far. Anyone see what I have wrong?

```
  var link_id = {{Click Path}}.split('=')[1];
  if({{Event}}.match(=.*)) return {{Event}};
  if(link_id.match(=.*)) return link_id;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```js
var link_id = {{Click Path}}.split('=').pop();
return link_id;
```

This uses `split()` to split the {{click Path}} variable at each occurrence of `=` sign and then uses `pop()` to extract the last element of the resulting array, which is the value after the last `=` sign in the URL.

EDIT:
Updated the code

```js
var link_id = {{Click Path}}.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
return link_id;
```

Now it first uses the `split()` method to split the `{{Click Path}}` variable at the first occurrence of the `?` character, and then uses a second `split()` to split the resulting string at each occurrence of the `=` character. The value after the last `=` sign in the URL is then extracted by accessing the second element of the resulting array.

Comment: your code returns "/go/company/" instead of what comes after = , like "link1". I would be ok /go/company/?aid=link1 as well. Any thoughts on how to change it to get either just what comes after = or just what comes after /go/ ?